# Upload_to with name of objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have a question I think it's easy to your guys about upload_to in Django but it's difficult to me. Hope your helps!

```
# Upload_to Def
from datetime import datetime
def avatar_country_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '%s' % (instance.id)
    datetime_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    return "geo/country/%s/%s_avatar.%s" %(filename, datetime_str, ext)

def cover_country_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '%s' % (instance.id)
    datetime_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    return "geo/country/%s/%s_cover.%s" %(filename, datetime_str, ext)

def flag_country_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '%s' % (instance.id)
    datetime_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    return "geo/country/%s/%s_flag.%s" %(filename, datetime_str, ext)

class BaseCountry(Place, SlugModel):
    # More
    avatar = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=avatar_country_path, blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=cover_country_path, blank=True)
    flag = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=flag_country_path, blank=True
```

As you see, I need 3 functions to make upload_to with a similar Path, just different in `NAME OF FIELDS (avatar, cover, flag)` but I dont know how to shorten it.

Could you guys help me?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Def" . These are functions, or methods.

Answer (score 3):

A trick for figuring out how to shorten code like this is to look for duplicate lines and then try to parameterize the rest like so:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def inject_field_type(instance, filename, suffix):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '%s' % (instance.id)
    datetime_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    return "geo/country/%s/%s_%s.%s" %(filename, datetime_str, ext, suffix)

def avatar_country_path(instance, filename):
    return inject_field_type(instance, filename, 'avatar')

def cover_country_path(instance, filename):
    return inject_field_type(instance, filename, 'cover')

def flag_country_path(instance, filename):
    return inject_field_type(instance, filename, 'flag')

class BaseCountry(Place, SlugModel):
    avatar = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=avatar_country_path, blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=cover_country_path, blank=True)
    flag = models.ImageField(max_length=1024, upload_to=flag_country_path, blank=True
```

This way you can change the logic required for creating the path an affect all 3 fields rather than having to change it in 3 different functions.

Comment: Anyway to just use ONE Def for 3 fields, bro?